# AngularJS, objects attached to $scope won't bind to html element

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding, scope

I have 3 files: `EventDetails.html`, `app.js`, and `EventController.js`.

Here is the body of the html

```
<html ng-app="eventsApp">
 <head>...</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div ng-controller="EventController">
    {{event.name}}</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

app.js:

```
var eventsApp = angular.module('eventsApp', []);
```

EventController.js:

```
eventsApp.controller('EventController',
    function EventController($scope) {
        $scope.event = {
            name: 'Angular',
            date: '2/23/16',
            time: '11:22 am'
        };
    });
```

when I run it, the view displays `"{{event.name}}"` and not `"Angular"`.
If everything looks like it should work, then I probably have an issue with my links in html to the JS pages.

Here it is in Plunker
http://plnkr.co/edit/T7Hexx9GEbp63eDxwCLE?p=preview

Comment: when you see {{event.name}} it is usually an indicator that there was an error. Have you checked the console to see if there are any?

Comment: doesn't look like you set an `ng-app="eventsApp"` either

Comment: create a plunker if possible?

Comment: thanks charlietfl, I just didn't show it here but I did have ng-app in the html tag

Comment: Basic code shown [works fine here](http://plnkr.co/edit/wzQVwq9SmAvKoZTAlKU5?p=preview)

Comment: @charlietfl, in my EventController.js it's saying "eventsApp" is undefined, but I don't have "var eventsApp = angular.module('eventsApp', []);" in my controller JS file, only app.js. Should I redefine the module/app in my controller file?

Comment: instead of using variable try `angular.module('eventsApp').controller(...` .   ... [like this](http://plnkr.co/edit/q6DqX2FcAvzVCqm8PYs0?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ive fixed it

on your plunker your script tags in head are very wrong

you need to point to angular and you need to point to your js files

ive changed them to ...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>

<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="EventController.js"></script>
```

and i changed the EventController file too ...

```
eventsApp.controller('EventController',
    function($scope) {  // NO NEED FOR FUNCTION NAME HERE
        $scope.event = {
            name: 'Angular',
            date: '2/23/16',
            time: '11:22 am'
        };
    });
```

job done

plunk of fix ... http://plnkr.co/edit/tkPrhZcxzTlLzLg6f65C?p=preview

hopefully u can view that